# How to hide server name when send email using php to gmail?

Tags: php, email, gmail

How to hide server name when send email using php to gmail?

I test my code on hotmail it's not show server name , But when i test send mail to gmail why gmail show server name. How to remove it's

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/b2b/Jqx7Zg.png

```
$headers = 'From: NUMBERONE<admin@numberone.com>' . "\n"; 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that the hostname is still there in hotmail (view email header/source). Gmail just chooses to make it visible for anti-spam/fraud reasons.

If you have reverse DNS setup for a static IP dedicated to your webserver you could resolve this.